# Let $a_n=1+\frac{1}{2n-1}$, $b_n=\tan^{-1}n,n\in\mathbb N$. Then which of the following is/ are true?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Question: Let $a_n=1+\frac{1}{2n-1}$, $b_n=\tan^{-1}n,n\in\mathbb N$. Then which of the following is/ are true?

$a).$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n+b_n|$ is convergent.

$b).$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|(a_n+b_n)-(a_{n+1}-b_{n+1})|$ is convergent.

$c).$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n+b_n|$ is divergent.

$d).$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|(a_n+b_n)-(a_{n+1}+b_{n+1})|$ is divergent.

The Question was asked in my test.

**My Attempt**:

$1.$ We have $|a_n+b_n|=|1+\frac{1}{2n-1}+\tan^{-1}n|$, this one is clearly divergent as it does not satisfy the initial criteria for convergence. So $a).$ false and $c).$ correct.

$2.$ For $b).$ and $d).$ we have $|(a_n+b_n)-(a_{n+1}-b_{n+1})|=|\frac{1}{2n-1}+\tan^{-1}(n)-\frac{1}{2n+1}-\tan^{-1}(n+1)|=|(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1})+(\tan^{-1}(n)-\tan^{-1}(n+1)|$, looks like **Telescoping Sum** but the terms are absolute valued so I guess that won't help us here. So further I reduced it as $|\frac{2}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}-\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{n(n+1)+1})|$. I was trying to make the use of comparison test here as the series is positive termed. If I use the expansion of $\tan^{-1}x=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\dots$, it will look like $|\frac{2}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}-\frac{1}{n(n+1)+1}+\frac{1}{3(n(n+1)+1)^3}\dots|$ . Now comparing it with $\frac{1}{n^2}$ did not gave me a non-zero limiting value, so this went in vain. This is where I am having trouble in proceeding ahead. I tried to form some inequalities too. I believe that $b).$ would be true.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: 1) $\frac 1 {2n-1}-\frac 1  {2n+1}=\frac 2 {(2n-1)(2n+1)}$

2. By Mean Value Theorem $\tan^{-1}(n+1)-\tan^{-1} n = [(n+1)-n] (tan^{-1})' x$ for some $x$ between $n$ and $n+1$. This gives $|\tan^{-1}(n+1)-\tan^{-1} n | \leq \frac  1 {1+n^{2}}$. Can you finish?

[b) is convergent by the same estimate. d) is convergent].

Comment: Nice use of MVT, thanks :)

Comment: Awesome solution. But I can't understand how it is divergent.  I thought the series 1/(n^2+1) and 2/(2n-1)(2n+1) are convergent. So summation is also convergent

Comment: @ShreyaJaganathan There was  a typo. I meant to say that c) is divergent.